# Angularjs - Store data to ng-model dynamically on drag drop within popup

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

I am working on drag drop functionality where one can drag node from list A(source) and drop to list B(destination).
I am facing problem of when once dragged and dropped first node and opens model on-click, I have to set some question within ng-repeat.
But when i am dropping same type of question, then values set to previous one is remains to newly dropped question's model.
How i can avoid such a problem?

I am using [this ui-tree example](http://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/cloning) for drag and drop.

Following image is snapshot of it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIJsQ.png][2]

Please share your opinion!

Comment: could you please put your code in `plnkr.co`

Comment: Hey @Sam, i have shared drag drop link